# Mongoose error handling in one place

Tags: node.js, error-handling, coffeescript, mongoose

I found in [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) that I can handle errors generally, that I want. So you can do like:

```
Product.on('error', handleError);
```

But what is the signature of this `handleError` method? I want something like this:

```
handleError = (err) ->
  if err
    console.log err
    throw err
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is standard in Node for `error` events to provide one argument, which is the error itself. In my experience, even the few libraries that provide additional parameters always leave the error as the first, so that you can use a function with the signature `function(err)`.

You can also check out the source on GitHub; here's the pre-save hook that emits an `error` event, with the error as an argument, when something goes awry: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/cd8e0ab/lib/document.js#L1140

There is also a pretty easy way in JavaScript to see all the arguments passed to a function:

```coffee-script
f = ->
  console.log(arguments)

f()                     # {}
f(1, "two", {num: 3})   # { '0': 1, '1': 'two', '2': { num: 3 } }
f([1, "two", {num: 3}]) # { '0': [ 1, 'two', { num: 3 } ] }
```

---

So now to the part where your function isn't working; how exactly does your code read? The name `handleError` isn't special in any way; you'll need one of these two:

**Option 1**: define the function, and pass a reference into the event registration:

```coffee-script
handleError = (err) ->
  console.log "Got an error", err

Product.on('error', handleError)
```

**Option 2**: define the function inline:

```coffee-script
Product.on 'error', (err) ->
  console.log "Got an error", err
```

Comment: I do this but I don't see my message in console when error occurs.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the handler won't run if you define a callback, so if you `Product.save(function(err, doc) {})`, it's expected that you're handling the error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Spent 1 hour finding the easy, common place & best way to do it:

Below code is in `express.js`:

In the `app.js`:

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

  // set locals, only providing error in development
  if (req.app.get('env') === 'development') {
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = err;
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    res.locals.message = 'Something went wrong. Please try again!';
    res.locals.error = {};
  }

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

In the `product-controller.js`:

```
let handleSuccess = (req, res, next, msg) => {
  res.send(msg + ' success ');
};

let handleError = (req, res, next, msg, err) => {
  // Create an error and pass it to the next function
  next(new Error(msg + ' error ' + (err.message || '')));
};
```

We could also put the above generic code in a common file, and import the file, to reuse the above functions in other controllers or any other file.